# Return array of objects (from array of objects)

Tags: javascript

I have the following data and I want to return an array (of objects) of `years` that are distinct.

I tried the following function but I'm getting an array within an array.

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "test1",
    years: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "year1"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "year2"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "test2",
    years: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "year1"
    }]
  },
]

let years = data.map((s) => {
  return s.years
})
let distinctYears = Array.from(new Set(years.map(c => c.id))).map(id => {
  return {
    id: id,
    name: years.find(c => c.id === id).name,
  }
})

console.log(distinctYears);
```

desired outcome:

```
[
  {id: 1, name: "year1"},
  {id: 2, name: "year2"}
]
```

Comment: What needs to be distinct, the id or the name? or both?

Comment: I want to return both, but distinct based on id. I included the desired outcome in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `s.years()` is an array, and `data.map()` returns an array of the results, `years` is necessarily an array of arrays.

Instead of using `.map()`, use `.reduce()` to concatenate them.

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "test1",
    years: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "year1"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "year2"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "test2",
    years: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "year1"
    }]
  },
];

const years = data.reduce((a, {
  years
}) => a.concat(years), []);
let distinctYears = Array.from(new Set(years.map(c => c.id))).map(id => {
  return {
    id: id,
    name: years.find(c => c.id === id).name,
  }
});
console.log(distinctYears);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's so many ways you can go about doing this. Here's one, it's not a one-liner but its broken down to parts to help us understand whats going on.

Your dataset:

```
let data =
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "test1",
    years: [{id: 1, name: "year1"}, {id: 2, name: "year2"} ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "test2",
    years: [{id: 1, name: "year1"} ]
  },
]
```

Use `.flatMap()` to create a one-level array with all items:

```
let allItems = data.flatMap((item) => {
    return item.years.map((year) => {
        return year
    })
})
```

Getting distinct items:

```
let distinct = []

allItems.forEach((item) => {
    let matchingItem = distinct.find((match) => match.id == item.id && match.name == item.name)

    if(!matchingItem){
        distinct.push(item)
    }
})
```

In Practice:

```js
let data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "test1",
    years: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "year1"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "year2"
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "test2",
    years: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "year1"
    }]
  },
]

let allItems = data.flatMap((item) => {
  return item.years.map((year) => {
    return year
  })
})

let distinct = []

allItems.forEach((item) => {
  let matchingItem = distinct.find((match) => match.id == item.id && match.name == item.name)

  if (!matchingItem) {
    distinct.push(item)
  }
})

console.log(distinct)
```